# Logic Pro 9 EVB3 Tonewheel Organ - Classic Organ Dry - House Bass preset values

Tags: software, logic-pro

Can someone please provide me with the values or a link to the preset? I'm using Logic Pro X and it doesn't have that preset.

Answer (score 3):

My Logic Pro X doesn't have this preset, nor does my LP9.

Are you sure this isn't a custom preset? My Logic Pro 9 shows the following organs in the library (bold entries are settings utilizing EVB3):

- **Abstract Organ**
- Angelic Organ
- Cathedral Organ
- **Circus Organ**
- **Classic Rock Organ**
- **Gospel Organ**
- **Heavy Metal Organ**
- **Jazz Organ**
- **Lounge Organ**
- Modulating Synth Organ
- **Old Radio Organ**
- **Percussive Organ**
- **Pop Organ**
- **Rock Organ**
- **Smooth Dance Organ**
- **Soul Organ**
- **Space Organ**
- Sparkling Organ
- Toy Organ
- **Trance Organ**
- Vocoder Synth Organ

Is the preset you're looking for in your ~/Library/Application Support/Logic/Plug-In Settings/EVB3/ folder?

Also, try searching your HD for `<insert patch name here>.pst`.

Do you have access to a project you used that patch with? If so, maybe it got saved in there.